# PermissionEvaluator not picked up after migration from @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to @EnableMethodSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an existing Spring Boot 6.0.3 project with Spring Boot Starter Security. I would like to swap deprecated `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation with `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity`, but when I do it, my `org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator` implementation is not picked up and `hasPermission` methods are not called.

I tried to:

1. Extend my security configuration class with `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, but this class is also deprecated, so it's not the solution for me.
2. Autowire my `PermissionEvaluator` implementation into security configuration class and create bean of type `org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` with `PermissionEvaluator` set through `setPermissionEvaluator` method. Although it creates security expression handler and sets permission evaluator, it causes `Bean 'xyz' of type [...] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors`.

The problem of the second step is that my `PermissionEvaluator` depends on services, which have methods annotated with `hasPermission` annotation and if those services are not postprocessed, those has permission checks no longer apply. I tried to split those `hasPermission`-annotated service methods into different class, but it only reduced the number of not post-processed classes from 212 to 172, which is way too much.

3. `BeanPostProcessor` - this is actually the same as the step 2, as I need to inject my `PermissionEvaluator` (I simply cannot construct it without other dependencies).
4. Create a custom `SecurityExpressionRoot` with my `PermissionEvaluator`, but this requires many additional custom classes and is not straightforward.

I'm thinking about setting the `PermissionEvaluator` after the app starts up, but this seems to me like circumventing the rules and I would like to avoid it, if there's any better solution.